# Почему не подключается css к Django

Tags: python, html, css, django, grid

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/main/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "main/static"
]
```

`index.html`:

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'main/css/style.css' %}">
<body>
  <div class="grid-wrapper">
    <header class="grid-header">
        <img class="circles" src="{% static "/img/main8.jpg" %}" alt="main pic">
        <p>Предоставим качественное образование, <br>
          поможем понять школьную программу, <br>
          улучшить оценки и <br>
          подготовиться к экзаменам</p>
    </header>
  </div>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

`base.html`:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'main/img/favico.png' %}">
  <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title> 
  <link rel = 'stylesheet' href = "{% static 'main/css/main.css' %}">
  <link rel = 'stylesheet' href = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
  <link rel = 'stylesheey' href = "https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
</head>
```

`style.css`:

```
.grid-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1 fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1 fr;
    grid-template-areas: 'header header';
}

.circles {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

p {
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
}

h1 {
    color: red;
}
```

Несколько раз изменял `settings.py`. Делал и по документации `Django`, и по видео-уроку. Удалял `main` в `static` и писал заново. Менял название `css` и `html` - файлов. Вне `static` всё работают. Изображения из `static/img` подключаются.

Comment: Мой ответ помог вам?

Answer (score 0):

Измените файл `settings.py` таким образом:

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
```

А в файле html просто добавляйте main:

```
{% static 'main/css/style.css' %}
```

Конечно можно оставить так же как у вас и сделано, просто поменяйте везде с "{% static 'main/css/style.css' %}" на "{% static 'css/style.css' %}".

Comment: Если я меняют с  "{% static 'main/css/style.css' %}" на "{% static 'css/style.css' %}", то все пропадает

Comment: Тогда измените по тому способу, который я указал выше

Comment: Css все равно не работает

Comment: css нужно подключать внутри тега `head`. Вот так вот должно быть:
 `<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
</head>`

Answer (score 0):

Что то подобное было. Джанго не видел ни css ни js. В итоге решил этот вопрос с помощью изменения подключения статики в settings.py Попробуйте этот код, я свой закоментил, вставил этот код и вуаля все мои изменения в статике заработали и все начало работать. Даже потом, когда я снова свой стандартный код раскоментил, а это подключение стаики убрал, все уже работало. Надеюсь поможет комуто. Мне так помогло. Отпишитесь кому поможет.

STATIC_URL = '/static/' STATICFILES_DIRS = ( 'static', ) STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

На сколько я понял, BASE_DIR дает нам каталог нашего проекта. Поэтому, когда мы делаете os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myproject/static'), это становится myproject/myproject/static. Или '/static'), надо указывать 'static/'),или попробуйте так '/').

Надеюсь поможет комуто. Мне так помогло. Отпишитесь кому поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь проблема в том, что твоя ссылка на твой css файл грузится перед ссылкой на бутстрап файл. переставь свой линк со своим css файлом в конец, и не забывай кликать в своем файле стилей ctrl + s, это так на всякий случай.